# Auto popup with close button using html, CSS

Tags: html, css

Hi I have code which generates a popup on button click.
But can any one please modify my code so that I can insert that code in my page and  get an auto popup on my page load.

I wish to insert this code in success page of project which appears after completion of a form.

```css
.box {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: orange;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>Here i am</h2>
  <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
  <div class="content">
   Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the [target CSS psuedo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors/Using_the_%3Atarget_pseudo-class_in_selectors).

Without JQuery you can use fragment identifiers. Any element whose ID matches the fragment identifier will automatically have the `:target` CSS psuedo-class applied to it.

You can then use CSS rules to hide the popup by default and show it when it is `:target`ed, (or the other way around), and add buttons to open and close the popup via navigating to the relevant fragment.

```css
.box {
    width: 20%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    padding: 35px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 20px/50px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    text-align: center;
}

.button {
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    border-radius: 20px/50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.button:hover {
    background: orange;
}

.popup {
    margin: 70px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 30%;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.popup .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    transition: all 200ms;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

.popup .close:hover {
    color: orange;
}

.popup .content {
    max-height: 30%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

/* These are the rules you are looking for. */
.overlay {
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}

.overlay:target {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <!-- This shows the popup. -->
    <a class="button" href="#popup">Let me Pop up</a>
</div> 

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup" >
        <h2>Here i am</h2>
        <!-- This hides it. -->
        <a class="close" href="#popup1">×</a>
        <div class="content">
            Thank to pop me out of that button, but now I'm done so you can close this window.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you do me one more fav please, If you can notice i'm not getting the pop up background shadow region on scroll down. Please fix it na...

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do an auto popup/lightbox on page load with CSS.

To make this work you will need to add a little jquery to your code above. This below will give you all the features you could want from the pop up

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

var id = '#dialog';

//Get the screen height and width
var maskHeight = $(document).height();
var maskWidth = $(window).width();

//Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
$('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

//transition effect
$('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
$('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9);  

//Get the window height and width
var winH = $(window).height();
var winW = $(window).width();

//Set the popup window to center
$(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
$(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

//transition effect
$(id).fadeIn(2000);     

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
//Cancel the link behavior
e.preventDefault();

$('#mask').hide();
$('.window').hide();
});

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
$(this).hide();
$('.window').hide();
});

});
```

And lastly add the jQuery library in the page

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery for that.
Check Below code working so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function(){
      
      $('#popup1').css("visibility", "visible"); 
       $('#popup1').css("opacity", 1); 
      
       });
  
  $( ".close" ).click(function() {
    
       $('#popup1').css("visibility", "hidden"); 
       $('#popup1').css("opacity", 0);
    });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: orange;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
 <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
 <div class="popup">
  <h2>Here i am</h2>
  <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
  <div class="content">
   Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you do me one more fav please, If you can notice i'm not getting the pop up on scroll down.

Comment: @atchyutnagabhairava for that you have to give height to overlay like `1024px;` because it's `position:absolute;`